# How do I prove that $x^s=(-1)^k \sum_{k=0}^{(r-1)/2}\binom{r}{2k}p^{s(r-2k)}$ has no solutions?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have been struggling to prove that the following diophantine equation has no integral solutions if $r$ is odd, $s,p>1$ $$x^s=(-1)^k \sum_{k=0}^{(r-1)/2}\binom{r}{2k}p^{s(r-2k)}$$ Any hint on how to approach this beast

Comment: Could you give some context or a source?

Comment: Is $(-1)^k$ inside the sum?

Comment: Is   p   prime? (4 more)

Comment: The sum is $\Re (p^s+i)^r$.

Comment: Shouldn't $k$ go up to $[r/2]$, not $r-1$?

Comment: @martycohen Cohen, $p$ is not necessarily a prime. Thanks $k $ should go up to $(r-1)/2$

Answer (score 1):

If $r=1$,
this becomes
$x^s = p^s$
which has the solution
$x = p$.

Comment: ,perhaps the way it was worded was misleading, $r>1$ and odd.

Answer (score 1):

If $r=3$,
this is
$x^s
=\binom{r}{0}p^{3s}-\binom{r}{2}p^{s}
= p^{3s}-\frac{r(r-1)}{2}p^s
= p^s(p^{2s}-3)
$.

By considering that
all the prime factors
of $x$ and $p$
are divisible by $s$,
this must also hold for
$p^{2s}-3$,
so
$p^{2s}-3
= d^s$
for some $d$.

Therefore
$d^s
= p^{2s}-3
$
or
$3
=p^{2s}-d^s
$.

$3
=p^{2s}-d^s
\ge (d+1)^s-d^s
\ge sd^{s-1}
$,
so $s \le 3$.
If $s = 3$,
$(d+1)^3-d^3= 3$
which has no solutions.
If $s=2$,
$3 \ge (d+1)^2-d^2
=2d+1
$
so $d=1$
and
$3=p^4-1$
which again
has no solutions.

Therfore
this has no solution
for $r = 3$.

Comment: That's a good start but it did not fully answer the question.

Comment: I noticed a simpler way to write this is $$(x/p)^s=\sum_{k=0}^{(r-1)/2}\binom{r}{2k}p^{s(r-2k-1)}(-1)^k$$ Knowing that the binomial expansion of $(p-1)^s$ is given by the formula $$(p-1)^s=\sum_{k=0}^{s}\binom{s}{k}p^{s-k}{(-1)^k}$$ Where do I go from there?

Comment: would the above comment help at generalizing your approach?